# How to simply combine field separated by a slash

Tags: bash

How to simply combine field separated by a slash ?

```
LIST=("a" "b" "c")
STRING=???

echo $STRING
a/b/c
```

Please someone help? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In BASH you can do:

```
list=("a" "b" "c")
printf -v str "%s/" "${list[@]}"
str="${str%/}"
```

Check output:

```
echo "$str"
a/b/c
```

Avoid all CAPS variables in BASH.

Alternatively using `IFS`:

```
str=$(IFS=/; echo "${list[*]}")
```

Comment: I'm coming back slash at the end : a/b/c/

Comment: [Check this working demo](http://ideone.com/pqwZqS)

Comment: Interestingly, the problem is with me.:-( Thank you..